# mousewheel doesn't work in swf (browser chrome)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash

All other browsers are ok (see  [bottom mid](http://ilempi.ru/konstruktor)). I can'n scroll list only in Chrome (all versions). I use this code:

```
package com.spikything.utils
{   import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import fl.controls.*;

    public class MouseWheelTrap
    {   static private var _mouseWheelTrapped:Boolean;
        public static function setup(list:List):void
        {
            list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,function():void { allowBrowserScroll(false); });
            list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,function():void { allowBrowserScroll(true); });
        }
        private static function allowBrowserScroll(allow:Boolean):void
        {
            createMouseWheelTrap();
            if (ExternalInterface.available)
            {
                ExternalInterface.call("allowBrowserScroll",allow);
            }
        }
        private static function createMouseWheelTrap():void
        {
            if (_mouseWheelTrapped)
            {
                return;
            }
            _mouseWheelTrapped = true;
            if (ExternalInterface.available)
            {
                ExternalInterface.call("eval","var browserScrolling;function allowBrowserScroll(value){browserScrolling=value;}function handle(delta){if(!browserScrolling){return false;}return true;}function wheel(event){var delta=0;if(!event){event=window.event;}if(event.wheelDelta){delta=event.wheelDelta/120;if(window.opera){delta=-delta;}}else if(event.detail){delta=-event.detail/3;}if(delta){handle(delta);}if(!browserScrolling){if(event.preventDefault){event.preventDefault();}event.returnValue=false;}}if(window.addEventListener){window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',wheel,false);}window.onmousewheel=document.onmousewheel=wheel;allowBrowserScroll(true);");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In main class:

```
MouseWheelTrap.setup(this.previewScrollBox);
this.previewScrollBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, this.showData);
```

And this javascript code - [swfobject.js](http://ilempi.ru/design/ilempi/js/swfobject.js)

Comment: May be something with hosting? Uploded this (https://code.google.com/p/mousewheeltrap/) to (http://ilempi.ru/demo/) and the same on Chrome =(

Answer (score 2):

Turning off pepperflash in chrome://plugins solved this problem. This stupid player is working with bugs. Or you can use this [BlastedMouseWheelBlock](https://github.com/KumoKairo/BlastedMouseWheelBlock)